# Populating Table Widget from Text File in Qt

Tags: qt, file, user-interface, widget

I'm new to Qt and need some help with the following:

I would like to create a GUI containing a Table Widget that is populated by information coming from a tab delimited text file. In my GUI, the user would first browse for the text file and then it would then show the contents in the Table Widget. I've done the browse part, but how do I load the data from the text file into the Table Widget?

Comment: This question is quite vague, are you using MVC or the 'traditional' widgets? A table widget is 2D, so how is the text going to be laid out in the table?

Comment: In the Qt Creator, there is a GUI control called Table Widget which is what I'm using. I thought the question was straightforward. I want to populate a table in my GUI with a tab delimited text file as the source of the data. If using a Table Widget, isn't the best approach then I'm open to other suggestions. As I mentioned, I'm new to Qt.

Comment: Well `QTableWidget` is the best option if you want to display only text, in a 2D grid, without sharing the data with any other widgets.  Also you will get a better response if you only asked a single question in your post: loading a text file, parsing it into separate strings, and then pushing them into a table widget; are three very different processes, and I'll be surprised if each of them aren't explained on this site or the docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's two steps, parse the file, and then push it into the widget.

I grabbed these lines from the [QFile documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html#details).

```
 QFile file("in.txt");
 if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
     return;

 while (!file.atEnd()) {
     QByteArray line = file.readLine();
     process_line(line);
 }
```

Your process_line function should look like this:

```
static int row = 0;
QStringList ss = line.split('\t');

if(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() < row + 1)
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(row + 1);
if(ui->tableWidget->columnCount() < ss.size())
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount( ss.size() );

for( int column = 0; column < ss.size(); column++)
{
    QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem( ss.at(column) );
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, column, newItem);
}

row++;
```

For more information about manipulating QTableWidgets, check the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html).  For new users using the GUI builder in Qt Creator, it is tricky figuring it out at first.

Eventually I would recommend to switching to building the GUI the way they do in all their [examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/all-examples.html)... by adding everything by hand in the code instead of dragging and dropping.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry...

```
void squidlogreader_::process_line(QString line)
{
    static int row = 0;
    QStringList ss = line.split('\t');

    if(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() < row + 1)
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(row + 1);
    if(ui->tableWidget->columnCount() < ss.size())
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount( ss.size() );

    for( int column = 0; column < ss.size(); column++)
    {
    QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem( ss.at(column) );
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, column, newItem);
    }

    row++;

}
void squidlogreader_::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFile file("in.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    while (!file.atEnd()) {
        QString line = file.readLine();
        process_line(line);
    }
```