# Qt GUI Table / Spreadsheet type layout in Ruby

Tags: ruby, qt, user-interface

I am trying to design a GUI that will output data in a spreadsheet type of format, rows and columns.

The cells will be populated with data that will be fetched by another object at predefined intervals. Being able to change individual cell color would be ideal to highlight any cells that have changed.

After some research it seems like QtBindings gem for ruby is the most powerful GUI choice for this but I can't seem to find any documentation or examples that would help me with what I am trying to accomplish. Any advice in the form of code or examples would be more than helpful. Thank you.

---

Update:: after some research and brute force, I came up with this code:

```
class PositionModel < Qt::AbstractTableModel
  slots 'timerhit()'

  def initialize(risk)
    super()
    @timer = Qt::Timer.new(self)
    connect(@timer, SIGNAL('timeout()'), self, SLOT('timerhit()'))
    @timer.start(1000)
    @risk = risk
    @risk_a = @risk.to_a
    #pp @risk_a
  end

  def timerhit()
    emit dataChanged(createIndex(0,0), createIndex(0,0))
    #emit dataChanged()
  end

  def rowCount(parent)
    @risk_a.size
  end

  def columnCount(parent)
    1
  end

  def data(index, role)
    col = index.column
    row = index.row


    if role == Qt::DisplayRole
      return Qt::Variant.new( @risk_a[row] )
    else
      return Qt::Variant.new()
    end 
  end
end


app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
model = PositionModel.new(@@risk)
table = Qt::TableView.new
table.model = model
table.setSortingEnabled(true)
table.show
```

It seems to be working well, and more importantly is a solid foundation for what I ultimately want to accomplish. However, I I tried to enable sorting by clicking on a column header, but it doesnt seem to be working. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Sorting a table in Qt is a completely different question.  I would open that one up in a new question on StackOverflow.  Btw, here is a starting place for info about it: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/2776

Answer (score 1):

Two words: Use `QTableView` or `QTableWidget`.

[Populating Table Widget from Text File in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608805/populating-table-widget-from-text-file-in-qt/10625144#10625144)

[How change row color with Null items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563839/how-change-row-color-with-null-items/14567757#14567757)

Converting the c++ code to ruby qt should be trivial.  Also the C++ Qt docs are awesome!  Good luck.

Hope that helps.